# Hide sheets in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an Tracker. Need help with these ideas:

1. When the Excel book is opened, it must show only the "Tracker" Worksheet. All other sheets need to be hidden. Now am using the code `{sheet.visible = xlveryhidden}` But the code is too long, I have to include each sheet name. I need help with a code to show only the Tracker sheet but to hide all other sheets in the workbook.
2. I've included two comboboxes as year and month. Also included a Command button OK & Cancel. When clicked on OK, it has to verify the IF condition and show a specific sheet. I have no issues with that. it is showing a specific sheet. But I need a single line code to hide all other sheets
3. I have also included a "New Tracker" Command button. When Clicked on it, it must include a New sheet. Also too let the user to rename it. This worksheet must also be hidden once saved.

I aware the process is simple, but not sure how to complete it.

Comment: show us your attempts please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To hide all but the Tracker worksheet

```
Sub hidesheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook 'Create the variables we'll use for our worksheet and workbook objects.
Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook 'Set the workbook variable to equal the active workbook. This can also be set to equal a named workbook if you want.

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets 'Loop through each worksheet in the workbook.
    If Not ws.Name = "Tracker" Then 'If the worksheet's name isn't "Tracker" then...
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden 'Set it to very hidden.
    Else 'If it is the "Tracker" worksheet, then ...
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible 'Set it to visible.
    End If 'End the IF/THEN statement.
Next ws 'Repeat for the next worksheet in the workbook.

End Sub
```

You'll have to modify this if you want it to work with a command button or do something with another worksheet. But it should get you started. I'd do it but I don't quite have the time right now.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted my answer, but I'm leaving it up regardless since I see nothing wrong with the code. Hope it helps!

Comment: I really appreciate for your help. It worked. Thank you Very much.. But Please assist for other queries whenever possible.